# extract words within special characters regex

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like this `{'id': '00045a8c33174826', 'url': 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/00045a8c33174826.json', 'place_type': 'city', 'name': 'Thanon Nakhon Chai Si', 'full_name': 'Thanon Nakhon Chai Si, Thailand', 'country_code': 'TH', 'country': 'Thailand', 'contained_within': [], 'bounding_box': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[100.5057265, 13.7741202], [100.5370861, 13.7741202], [100.5370861, 13.800442499999999], [100.5057265, 13.800442499999999]]]}, 'attributes': {}}`

I would like to get the output: `TH`

Could anyone help me do this quickly? I have tried this but it does not seem correct:

```
re.search("'country_code': '(\w)'", text)
```

Thank you.

Update: I have used

`df.str.extract(r"'country_code': '(\w)'")`

Comment: Are you trying to parse JSON content, and, if so, can you include the full string?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I have included the full string. Thanks.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/chyhsJ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
r"'country_code': '(.*)'"
```

That regular expression would provide the following result:

```py
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"'country_code': '(.*)'")
>>> string = "'country_code': 'TH'"
>>> regex.search(string).group(1)
'TH'
>>>
```

However, if this is JSON content, I would recommend using the Python StdLib `json` module:

```py
>>> import json
>>> string_data = "{...}"
>>> data = json.loads(string_data)
>>> data["country_code"]
'TH'
```

Using this method would allow you to retrieve the values for other keys in the dictionary without having to create an entire set of regular expressions.

Comment: If you use the entire string that OP gave, you will get more than you wanted. You may want to address this. Set your string to the entire string OP gave to see what I am referring to. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: I think you want to change `regex` to `regex = re.compile(r"'country_code': '([^']*)'")`. This will match `'` followed by anything not a single quote, then followed by a single quote `'`.

Comment: Forget the regex, loading it as JSON is the better way to do it. One issue, Jacob, is that the provided string is not valid JSON and `.loads()` will choke on it. You need to replace `'` with `"` before you send it to `.loads()`. You can do that simply using `string_data = "{...}".replace("'", "\"")`.

Comment: @JeffC: I am trying to loading this as JSON. However, after replace ' with ", there is an error: ```JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter```. Could you please help? Thanks.

Comment: @Jason It's best if you ask a new question rather than trying to sort it all out here in the comments of a different question. Post what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and the specific error message. If I don' t see it, someone else surely will and help you.